# Session vs access token + refresh token

Tags: session, cookies, oauth-2.0, access-token, bearer-token

It looks like there are multiple blog posts that are against storing tokens in anyway in the browser (strict no to localstorage/sessionStorage/in-memory variable). The only way suggested is to use server side sessions + HTTPS + httpOnly cookie. So, can below be considered more or less a recommended way?

1. Use server side sessions + HTTPS + httpOnly + SameSite=Strict cookies for browser based clients (just don't support older browsers at all) + Only support application/json based POST/PUT requests
2. Use Access tokens + refresh tokens + PKCE for mobile clients

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty much the best practice state of things:

- A browser client has nowhere secure to store tokens so uses the latest `SameSite=strict` HTTP only cookies. These can contain tokens if they are strongly encrypted with a key only known to the server.
- A mobile client cannot easily use cookies, but can use encrypted secure storage to save tokens. Also use the AppAuth pattern and consider the use of https redirect URIs that no malicious app can abuse.
- APIs receive JWT access tokens and verify them on every request. Note that a reverse proxy can sit in front of APIs to manage decrypting received cookies and forwarding them to APIs, as described in [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-proxy-plugin-lua/).

Of course you should understand the reasoning behind these recommendations. Curity have some articles that provide further info, in case useful:

- [SPA Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/)
- [Mobile Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-for-mobile-apps-best-practices/)
- [API Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/api-security-best-practices/)

Also see [Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/), since implementing flows correctly and using good libraries are also important factors.

Comment: Thanks Gary. If I edit my question to include SameSite=Strict restriction for cookies, is my approach correct for what we have currently?

Comment: Yes - looks broadly in line with best current practices. The devil is in the detail though, such as making good choices of security libraries so that all the right checks are made. You may find our website resources useful so I've added some links above.